# Java bindBidirectional

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, binding

I have the following problem. My task is to create a double bond between my sudoku field object and its graphical form in the GUI. So far I've managed to come up with something like this.

```
TextField textField = new TextField();

JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder builder = JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder.create();
JavaBeanIntegerProperty test =  builder.bean(board.getSudokuField(i,j))
        .name("FieldValue").build();
StringConverter<Number> converter = new NumberStringConverter();
Bindings.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), test, converter);
```

The solution works, but if you enter any character other than a number, it throws a parse error.

> Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "a"

Is this the best way to somehow change the type of bond? Or adding a condition regarding the input values,but I just don't know how to do it.
board.getSudokuField(i,j) return SudokuField Object.
And there are int getFieldValue() which return int and void setFieldValue(int value)

Comment: Use a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to ensure only valid values are entered in the text field. It's usually better to bind to the formatter's `valueProperty` instead of the text. It might also be better to build your `SudokuField` class with JavaFX properties instead of using plain Java beans and the adapter.

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: If you have a working version, you can [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so others can see the code for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my solution, the numbers entered into the TextField can only be a number between 1 and 9.

```
 TextField textField = new TextField();

                JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder builder =
                        JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder.create();
                JavaBeanIntegerProperty test =  builder.bean(board.getSudokuField(i,j))
                        .name("FieldValue").build();
                StringConverter<Number> converter = new NumberStringConverter();

            textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(c -> {
                if (c.isContentChange()) {
                    if (c.getControlNewText().length() == 0) {
                        return c;
                    }

                    try {
                        Integer.parseInt(c.getControlNewText());
                        if (Integer.parseInt(c.getControlNewText()) > 9
                                || Integer.parseInt(c.getControlNewText()) == 0) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        return c;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                        ignored.getMessage();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                return c;
            }));
                Bindings.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), test, converter);
```